# '.Find' method simply won't return anything

Tags: vba, excel

Essentially my code just finds a certain cell containing an index coordinate provided by a Spin Button from a form. It is just a segment of the whole code, and the whole code worked absolutely perfectly and was fast, before I reopened the code this morning to continue coding. I changed absolutely nothing after I saved the last time, and through some debugging, I've found that the .Find method, for some reason, returns nothing, although the data is there and even if I fill the entire column with the same data it's supposed to find, it won't return anything. Thus the code yields:

> "object variable or With block variable not set"

every time it tries to use the object.

```
Set DR = Worksheets("Detalle - Reporte")

If spinCapituloVal.Value = 0 Then
    MsgBox ("Por favor, introduce un capítulo válido")
    Exit Sub
End If

With Columns(2)
Set Finder = .Find(spinCapituloVal.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, MatchCase:=False)
End With

If Finder Is Nothing Then
MsgBox ("No se encontró el capítulo especificado")
Exit Sub
End If

indiceCapActual = Finder.Value
indiceCapSiguiente = Finder.Offset(1, 0).Value

If indiceCapSiguiente = "" Then

    With DR.Columns(1)
        Set capActual = .Find(indiceCapActual, LookIn:=xlValues, MatchCase:=True)
        Set capActualGuia = capActual.End(xlDown)
    End With

Else

    With DR.Columns(1)
        Set capActual = .Find(indiceCapActual, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)
        Set capSiguiente = .Find(indiceCapSiguiente, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)
    End With

End If
```

All I want to know is why in the world the .Find method just stopped working, and how can I avoid it in the future?

Comment: change `With Columns(2)` to `With DR.Columns(2)`.

Comment: Find is SLOW. Use Match instead:  https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/10/26/match-vs-find-vs-variant-array-vba-performance-shootout/

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying; the first .Find works just fine. its the one that involves the other worksheet that failed out of nowhere.

Comment: is it the `MatchCase:=True` setting that may be throwing it off on the 2nd `.Find` groupings?

Comment: Tried it with and without the MatchCase, and in both `True` and `False`. It shouldn't even matter, because the string i'm searching is a number (Spin Button Value). @ScottHoltzman

Comment: well, it could've have matter since you don't use `LookAt:=xlWhole` when you initially `Set = Finder ...`. What line of your code do you receive the error you mentioned?

Comment: Let me explain the code further: the "Finder" object is just a cell that contains the value that you put in the Form. That cell is in a table in a certain worksheet. What I do in the rest of the code, is to do a series of operations in **another** worksheet to a certain range that has a guide number equal to the value of Finder. Precisely what I'm doing in this fragment, is retrieving the value of Finder and then looking for it in another Worksheet. I work just fine 5 hours ago; i open it again, try to run the command, and boom; nothing. Get the error above. @ScottHoltzman

Comment: I get what the code is doing. What exact **line of code** do you receive the error on? And when you `Set Finder = ` do you get the result you expect in terms of value (or say, range.address)?

Comment: Part of the issue could be the `ActiveSheet`.  Is your `DR` worksheet the active one? I would specify which worksheet you need to refer to at this line: `With Columns(2)` (just before you set `Finder` the first time) and change that to `With [worksheet].Columns(2)`...  Also, when you use that Find, try specifying what part of the object you need, i.e. `Set Finder = .Find(spinCapituloVal.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, MatchCase:=False).Address` or `.Row`, etc.

Comment: in the one that says `Set capActualGuia = capActual.End(xlDown)`. And it throws this error because capActual is `Nothing`; ergo the .Find method returned `Nothing` @ScottHoltzman

Comment: when you `Set capActual = ` is the value for `indiceCapActual` what you would expect it to be? And what happens if you open the `Find` dialogue manually at this line break. That may give you a clue as to why it can't find the data you say is there. (I.e. - extra spaces or something?)

Comment: Yes, its supposed to be a number, but `.Find` shouldn't care about that.

Comment: There is no room for extra spaces, it's the direct value of the cell.

Comment: you still did not answer my question: is the value for `indiceCapActual` what you expect it to be? If you debug the code and check that value is it what you think it should be based on the SpinButton option?

Comment: I found what happened, and it seems such ridiculous NONSENSE that I urge Microsoft to fix this. Apparently, I saved the worksheet with a different column width that didn't allow for the cell to display it's content properly (column is `Fill` formatted). After giving the column the proper width again the code ran flawlessly. I am in complete and total confusion with this. This is just... Why in the world would this even happen? Thanks for your help, @ScottHoltzman

Comment: @zickens Please follow my advice. Do not use `Find`. It's finicky and slow. Always use Match, which is blazingly fast and does not suffer the quirks that `Find` does.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my problem was a highly unexpected one. The column where I was using the `.Find` method with `capActual` didn't have enough width so as to display its contents properly, and this somehow stopped `.Find`from finding the cell that contained the value. Yes. The column width.

Giving the column enough room to display the contents solved the problem.